# Display mathematics symbols in Typora

Tags: markdown

I read the leetcode's official solution to [reverse an integer](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/solution)

Upon copying the following to my markdown notes

[image]

but got

[image]

I use typora which is usually powerful.

Why the contents failed to display as it is on the website?

Comment: Please post the actual source Markdown text as a code block as well as the generated HTML. Screenshots are not very helpful in determining these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The text you're copying contains ***katex***, which isn't supported by [Typora](https://github.com/typora/typora-issues/issues/888). So you should use Latex syntax to render Mathematics expressions.

In typora, you could just press $$ and Return key to input a [math block](https://support.typora.io/Math/#math-block-display-math). But in your case, you need inline math. Press `command/ctrl + ,` and make sure *inline math* is checked.

[image: screenshot image]

To use inline math, put your content between $. For example `$f(x)=x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}$` results

[image: screenshot image]

If you write following in Typora

```
To explain, lets assume that $\text{rev}$ is positive.

1. If $temp=rev\cdot10+pop$ causes overflow, then it must be that $rev\geq\frac{INTMAX}{10}$
2. If $rev>\frac{INTMAX}{10}$, then $temp=rev\cdot10+pop$ is guaranteed to overflow.
3. If $rev==\frac{INTMAX}{10}$, then $temp=rev\cdot10+pop$ will overflow if and only if $pop>7$

Similar logic can be applied when $\text{rev}$ is negative.
```

It looks like,

[image: screenshot]

Here `\cdot` results multiplication dot (**⋅**), `\geq` results **≥** and `\frac{}{}` results fractions.

See all the [Latex Math Symbols](http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html) and [difference between dot characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19180/which-dot-character-to-use-in-which-context).